# Databinding CustomControls within PivotControls

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to use a PivotControlPage to control the paging of an object with a List

My current attempt is like so

```
    <controls:Pivot x:Name="quizPivot" Title="MY APPLICATION" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" SelectedIndex="1" >

        <controls:PivotItem Header="{Binding QuestionTitle }">
            <Grid>
                <local:Text5Control DataContext="{Binding .}"></local:Text5Control>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>

    </controls:Pivot>
```

I want the pivot control to control the "next" and "previous" actions and pass that current item to the DataContext of my custom control.

I'm doing this slightly wrong I think, but i'm setting the DataContext of the pivotcontrol and the currentitem in the code behind.

this is where i set the datacontext for the pivot control

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        quiz = new Quiz();
        quiz.Questions = loadQuestions()  // loads questions from file

        quizPivot.DataContext = quiz;
    }
```

Comment: What's not working - what is it doing that's different than what you expect? Also, can you post the code where you set the DataContext?

Comment: it gives me Namespace+Class rather than the value of that record, the pivot table also actually pivots but the display of the data is that.

Comment: i not have an x:name for the pivot table and i have the datacontext set in the innavigatedto method as i'm using params to sort the dataset

Comment: Does the PivotItem's header bind correctly? Are you seeing QuestionTitles?

Comment: Also, what is a Text5Control?

Comment: a text5control is just a custom control which should display an individual "question" and does when used on it's own (without the pivot).

Comment: Without seeing the code, I can't be sure, but I suspect the problem is how you're setting the DataContext for the Pivot. Can you post the code?

Comment: i've added the code to my onNavigatedTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the xaml to look like this.

```
    <controls:Pivot x:Name="quizPivot" Title="Mensa" SelectedIndex="1" DataContext="{Binding quiz}" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionTitle}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <local:Text5Control DataContext="{Binding .}"></local:Text5Control>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

What I was missing is the use of templates for the data. PivotItem is only applicable for static items.